# how to had conditional class in a method helper?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, class, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I'd like to had a conditional class in a method helper

**product_helper.rb**

```
def product_icon
  ...
  elsif product.sent?
    '<div class="green-text  <%= 'middle' if current_action?(controller: 'products', action: 'index')" %> ><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>'.html_safe
end
```

But I get this ERROR :

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting keyword_end 
 '<div <%= 'class="middle if current_acti...
                  ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the helper, so you cannot use `<%= ... %>` but need to use `#{....}`

Your helper should return this:

```
return "<div class='green-text <%= 'middle' if current_action?(controller: 'products', action: 'index')'%>><i class='fa fa-envelope-o' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>".html_safe
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely forget this details! But it's not interpretate as html in the views, even with the '#{...}' do you know why ?

Comment: even with the `.html_safe`?

Comment: Yes even whit the .html_safe. This is the exact view render : <div class="green-text  #{middle if current_action?(controller: " products",="" action:="" "index")}""><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

Comment: you have of course need to replace the `'` with `"`